# iOS 11 app not waking to for push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have built an app that supports push notifications. I am trying to figure out how to wake my app when I get a push notification so that I can kick off a download process to update my app data. The problem I am running into is when the app is in the background it doesn't receive the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` even though the push notification is shown on the device and I do include the `content-available` attribute in the aps payload. Please see relevant code samples below.

Screenshot of my capabilities tab in Xcode.

[image]

Please note I have also tried to enabled Background fetch but that doesn't do anything different.

Here is how I register for remote notifications

```
let rejectAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "reject", title: "Reject", options: [.destructive])
    let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "accept", title: "Accept", options: [.foreground])
    let actionCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "ACTIONABLE", actions: [rejectAction, acceptAction], intentIdentifiers: [rejectAction.identifier, acceptAction.identifier], options: [.allowInCarPlay])

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.setNotificationCategories([actionCategory])

    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }

    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Here is how I respond to remote notifications

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    NSLog("** [VoiceAppLog] Push Notification Received - didReceiveRemoteNotification **");

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let str = NSString(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        NSLog("[VoiceAppLog] userInfo: \(String(describing: str))")
    } catch {

    }

    // Make API calls here

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Here is a sample of the content payload I am sending with slight modifications to de-identify the product I'm working on.

{
"my_category" : 1,
  "custom_attribute_boolean" : false,
  "aps" : {
    "content-available" : 1,
    "alert" : "Test Message",
    "badge" : 1,
    "sound" : "custom_sound.caf"
  }
}

As you can see and from what I can tell I am doing everything correct based on the documentation. One thing that is interesting is when I have the app connected to my debugger and I put the app in the background, then the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called correctly. However, as soon as I disconnect the debugger it is no longer called. This happens even if I reopen the app and background it without force quitting the app. The same occurs for production builds via TestFlight. As soon as the app goes into the background then the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` protocol method is no longer called.

I am curious if I'm running into the iOS bug as explained [here](https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/2017/09/28/apple-push-notification-changes-ios-11/). Do any of you all out there in Internet Land have any ideas how to resolve/work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Which tool are you using to send notification. Apparently since the notification is being shown, it's not being treated as "silent push" but as "remote" notification

Comment: Im using AWS Simple Notification Service. I’ve tried to not send any other attributes, such as the alert and sound, and had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this issue was to use a VoIP push notification, and then respond to that in my app delegate and update content. A VoIP push notification will always wake an app regardless of the app state. I know it's not necessarily the correct use for a VoIP notification, but it works :)